# How can I migrate from aws elasticache to azure redis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, redis, cloud, amazon-elasticache

I have been checking on internet for quite a some time but could not find any useful information regarding this cause every page says elasticache for redis but not on how I can migrate from aws elasticache to azure redis. On azure I can see that I can migrate from other redis cache to azure redis cache but not from aws elasticache to azure redis. Can someone show me the point where I should start my research on this cause its taking up so much of time with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Elasticache supports two back-end technologies: Redis and Memcached. Which of those are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,   I found a way to migrate elasticcache memcached to redis which I have been working on for the past some time...I migrated the cache from elastic memcached to redis and the migrating redis to azure redis. Is it possible to avoid migrating twice?    (from memcached).